# ssrs reports line chart how to add category group based on the column data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I am developing a sql server report which is basically conversion of an excel report. Without modifying the sp, i would like to create a sql server line chart report.

i have the rows returned something like this:

Date             Technicianname TechnicianType  IssuesFixed

2011-03-04        XXXXX           engineer        20
2011-03-04        YYYYY           sr.Engineer     35
2011-03-05        ZZZZZ            engineer       22
2011-03-05        WWWWW            sr.engineer    40

My line graph should be one line progress shows for engineer and other line shows progress for sr.engineer.

While i add the category groups, i can use aggregate functions but not  any filters.. like techniciantype=engineer, techniciantype=sr.engineer.

Could you please guide me how can i proceed with it..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Date as Category Field, IssuesFixed as Data Field, and TechnicianType as the Series Field.  Then you will have two progress lines, one for Engineer and Sr. Engineer, with Date on the horizontal axis, IssuesFixed on the vertical axis.  If you want to filter for individual names, or for any other variable, right-click on the 'variable/box' you want to filter in the Data Field, and select Filter on the left pane of the dialog, and set your filter there.